# Is there a psychological scale/measurement that can be used to determine how much of a 'victim mentality' the subject has?

Tags: measurement, test

Is there an accepted test/scale/measurement/etc that can be used to measure how much of a 'victim mentality' the subject has?

Comment: Would you mind adding a link to a formal definition of "victim mentality" to make sure people trying to answer know what you're talking about?

Comment: Unfortunately I've had difficulty finding a formal definition. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victim_mentality) on this topic lacks citation in a lot of places.

Comment: I had the same problem. Consequently, I'm not sure it's a valid/useful/grounded psychological concept.

Comment: "Victim mentality" in my experience is most often used as a pejorative, so you should probably be careful with how you intend to use the term - the Wikipedia article seems to attempt to make it a more neutral term, but I think that's probably a mistaken approach. You could look for the concept of "persecution" where people think they are being fairly or unfairly treated, often in the context of schizophrenic paranoia, but this may not overlap entirely with what you have in mind.

Comment: On top of what @BryanKrause has pointed out, there are those who see some people as constantly "needing" to be a victim because they get attention and are rescued.  Please try and clarify what you mean by 'victim mentality'

Comment: It might be possible to walk the question back and ask instead if this is a useful concept in psychology, or if there are any concepts in use that might be similar. Based on answers there, a follow-up question could refer to answers to that question.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I believe all these comments point out a clear problem: you cannot hope to measure what you haven't defined. I believe @uhoh's suggestion is the best way forward, as asking for potential related terms in psychology is your best bet at finding instruments which measure it. You can either delete this question and ask a new one, or edit this one accordingly.